# How to Stop Android Studio from Unfolding Code on Hot Reload

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

In Android Studio, in my case with Flutter and Dart, on every Hot Reload, all code unfolds. So, if I've folded (minimized) comments or a class or function, or widget tree, on hot reload, Android Studio expands everything back.  It's extremely annoying, and I haven't found a suitable solution.  There is no option to stop this in the folding settings in preferences. (that I've found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot auto-format code on save and preserve your folding.  In Preferences, Languages & Frameworks, Flutter: if you have "Format code on save" ticked, this will unfold all code in the act of checking for formatting.

So "Format code on save" is incompatible with preserving your minimized (folded) code.

On a mac: cmd-option-L will format code, but it will unfold everything while doing it.  Instead, do the following:

1. Go to preferences, Keymap
2. Open Main Menu, then Code
3. Find "Reformat Code with 'dart format'
4. Double click that and create a keyboard shortcut.  I suggest ctrl-option-L

Now you can format without unfolding, unlike option-cmd-L, which unfolds everything.